# How to call static block into a phtml file Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have static block in backend named as "varmo_custom_block_for_header".

I want to echo that block content into a `header.phtml` file.

I trying this way but not succeed :

```
 <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('varmo_custom_block_for_header')>toHtml();?>
```

But getting error as :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function toHtml() in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/xyz/app/design/frontend/xyzthemes/mo/xyzthemes_mo/templates/html/header.phtml
>   on line 47

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code in near `>toHtml`

It should be `->toHtml()`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class)->setBlockId('varmo_custom_block_for_header')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: @shail if this answer help you then you can mark as accepted, so other users take benifit if they face same problem

Comment: @ Murtuza  i vote cast for "This answer is useful".

Comment: @shail you can hit that green ` ✔` button next to my answer for this

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

This is another option:

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```